# Why do I still get "Terminated due to timeout error" even after using deque instead of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, timeout, deque

I have written the following code to output the number of distinct words from the input and also their number of occurrences for each distinct word according to their appearance in the input.

I used the list append and count method and got the desired output, but some of the test cases didn't execute due to timeout error.

```
n = int(input())
ar = []
for _ in range(n):
    ar.append(input().rstrip())

def wordOrder(n, ar):    
    w_list =[] #list contains the number of repition of words
    u_list =[] #list eliminates the duplicates while maintaining the same order
    for i in ar:
        if i not in u_list:
            u_list.append(i)
            w_list.append(ar.count(i))
       
    return w_list
    
result = wordOrder(n, ar)
print(len(result))
print(*result, sep=' ')
```

So, I tried using deque instead of list thinking it might be due to the time complexity issue of O(n) for the list append method. But I am getting the same error even after using deque.

My question is whether the problem is due to the time complexity issue or some other factors? Would be great if someone could explain what kind of techniques to be adapted to avoid timeout error.

Sample Input:

```
4
bcdef
abcdefg
bcde
bcdef
```

Sample Output:

```
3
2 1 1
```

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure for this problem. How about a dictionary?

Comment: `deque` and `list` have similar performance for `append` operations. You should use `deque` if your code has lots of  `appendLeft` kind of operations.

Comment: Also, you can get a timeout error if your program takes up too much space.

Comment: @Shiva Thanks for the suggestion. It seems like I shouldn't use deque in this kind of situation as a replacement for a list.

Comment: @zenalc Yes, I tried using a dictionary to solve this problem but the order in which they got arranged brought an issue. Didn't think of using Counter() because I thought the same order problem would be there. But Counter() now worked fine for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me

```
from collections import Counter

a=[]

for i in range(int(input())):

      a.append(input())

x = Counter(a)

print(len(x.keys()))

print(*x.values())
```

Comment: Yes, this code solves the problem. Thanks for it! So is it using the list append method complicated the problem? Also, it seems like I should avoid deque unless it is used for its intended purpose like appendLeft operation. Is that so?

Comment: A Counter is a subclass of dict. It is an unordered collection where elements and their respective count are stored as a dictionary.

Comment: Well, that looks like a pretty simple way of solving this one. Maybe helpful for me to solve similar kinds of coding problems in python.

Answer (score 0):

Though just using Counter() luckily works in this problem, it is safe to use OrderedDict() so as to maintain the existing order of the input provided. Therefore, the below code should work fine in all similar situations and it didn't bring any "Timeout error" which is what I wanted.

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

a=[]

for i in range(int(input())):

      a.append(input())

x = OrderedDict(Counter(a))

print(len(x.keys()))

print(*x.values())
```